# How to set up custom domain correctly for github pages repository?

Tags: github-pages, cname

What I want to achieve is that I want a custom domain name to be applied to my github page.  I want to achieve the followings:

1. when user enter `xx.yy.zz` in the address bar, it will show my blog site, which is http://myuser.github.io
2. when user click a blog I wrote, the address bar should show the address `xx.yy.zz/2016/03/20/The_title_of_my_blog`

Currently, I've achieve the first point by set up a `url redirect record` at the domain provider, but when user open a blog, the address doesn't change, it remains to be: `xx.yy.zz`. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I just did this myself with a site I'm working on, you need to start with adding a CNAME record in your github repository do this by adding a new file, naming it CNAME and then putting your domain or subdomain in the file e.g.

domain.com
or 
www.domain.com
or
subdomain.domain.com

then you'll need to add either an A record or a CNAME record with your domain provider that points to github servers

[This page](https://help.github.com/articles/quick-start-setting-up-a-custom-domain/) takes you through the steps to do all this, depending on how you want to set up your domain